# How to open Saved Photos Album when touch a button?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a simple IOS application, and there is a feature that user can save the image of current screen, after user take a screenshot, I will inform them "the image was saved, would you like to open the album?" if user select yes, then open the album, now I can launch the Save Photos album with the following code(this is the event handler when user type the yes button)

```
- (IBAction)gotoPhotoAlbum:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 320, 350)];
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is as soon as I click a photo(thumbnail) in the album, it returns to my app, give me no chance to view the photo, what I want is user can view/edit the photo just as if they open albums directly, and when they done the operation, return to my app, is that possible?

Comment: The clue is in the name if the used class: `UIImagePickerController`. It is an image picker, as in it allows the user to select an image. You can not launch the image app on iOS because there is no know app url scheme for it. So you will have to write you own image viewer.

Comment: lots of great classes on http://cocoacontrols.com/ that will do this